# How to change the RN screen content according to the selected language?

Tags: react-native

I want to change my RN applications language according to the user selected language. How can I achieve this with react-native? Is react-native-localize  the library that I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `i18n-js` and `react-native-localize`

**Install Modules**

```
yarn add react-native-localize
yarn add i18n-js

OR

npm install --save react-native-localize
npm install --save i18n-js
```

And

react-native link react-native-localize

**Example.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import * as RNLocalize from "react-native-localize";
import i18n from 'i18n-js';
const en = {
  foo: 'Foo',
  bar: 'Bar {{someValue}}',
};
const fr = {
  foo: 'como telle fous',
  bar: 'chatouiller {{someValue}}',
};

i18n.fallbacks = true;
i18n.translations = { fr, en };
i18n.locale = RNLocalize.locale;
export default class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 50, alignSelf: 'center' }}>
        {i18n.t('foo')} {i18n.t('bar', { someValue: Date.now() })}
      </Text>
    );
  }
}
```

I recommend that you create and manage files by `json` in each language of the country rather than by example method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, How does the app know, which language it should use?
 en or fr?? How does the app identify the current language??

Comment: It is the problem of the app creator to decide which language the app's creator will use. This module can tell you the language by reading the language used in mobile phones.

Comment: `fr`is French and `en` is English

Comment: @Shashika If the answer was helpful, could you choose a my answer?

Comment: Sure. Sorry I forgot it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use react-native-localize to get the users locale.

Using the `findBestAvailableLanguage` method you can get the best language out of your available subset:

```
console.log(RNLocalize.findBestAvailableLanguage(["en-US", "en", "fr"]));
```